Nyc instrumentation code coverage report containing instrumented code
I am using nyc instrumentation and cypress code coverage plugin (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage). Using npx nyc instrument I instrument my app, so cypress can intercept the counters and calculate how many ties each function is used. However, in lcov report, the code is still instrumented instead of being raw. Why is that?.
.nycrc file inside angular project:
{
  "parser-plugins": [
    "typescript",
    "decorators"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.component.ts",
    "**/*.service.ts",
    "**/*.constant.ts"
  ],
  "instrument": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "require": [
    "ts-node/register"
  ]
}

.nycrc file inside cypress:
{
  "reporter": ["lcov"],
  "instrument": true,
  "sourceMap": true,

}

Tried adding various flags to .nycrc file inside cypress folder (seems it has to be there to specify report type) but nothing helped.
